# C# Winform Menustrip Toolstripitem change image on mouse hover time delay issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have menustrip with 5 items. I have set a image to each toolstripitem. Now, I wish to change the image whenever hover the toolstripitem and I used the below code.

```
        void item_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ToolStripItem).Image = Resources.gray;
    }

    void item_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ToolStripItem).Image = Resources.blue;
    }
```

And it works fine. But I need to wait a second to view the blue image. How do I resolve this time delay?

Comment: @Tombala is correct...the Hover event has a built-in delay, like tooltip.  MouseEnter is instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.mouseenter.aspx) event instead of mouse hover.